# Closing a browser using python

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to make an internet radio based on opening and closing the web browser to start and stop the radio but I can't for some reason close the browser using different methods.

I have already tried using the **subprocess** method.

```
import subprocess as sp
web = sp.Popen("epiphany http://www.google.com", shell=True)
```

but after doing that i could neither close the process with

```
web.kill()
```

nor with

```
web.terminate()
```

It simply did nothing.

I also tried using the selenium method but as I am trying to do this on a raspberry pi, so the only browser is epiphany that is not supported and I could not get a different supported browser to install.

The webbrowser module in python does not seem to have any closing function

Is there a way I could manage to close the browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Comment: Why don't you use Selenium?

Comment: @GeorgePetrov as i said, i am doing this on a raspberry pi 3 and i couldnt get a browser to install so i have to use epiphany (lightweight browser for the pi) but it is not supported by selenium unless i got the concept all wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing alot of research i found out that i could kill the browser by typing

```
pkill epiphany
```

into the terminal so i just used this code to close it in python:

```
import os
os.system("pkill epiphany")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to close the browser that just opened. Assuming that you only have one epiphany instance open, you can use

```
sp.Popen("killall epiphany")
```

Which will kill all instance of epiphany.
If you have multiple instances you will need to get the id of the running epiphany that you want to kill.

```
sp.Popen("epiphany http://www.google.com & export PID=$!", shell=True)
# Do Stuff Here With Epiphany
sp.Popen("kill -9 $PID")
```

This should open a new epiphany instance to www.google.com, and save PID into your environment variables. Then, you can get the value of PID using $PID and kill the browser process.

Comment: this for some reason did not work for me. both methods raise a child_exception with the reason "no such file or directory" i also noticed that if i do 'echo $PID' while epiphany is running with the second method it does not return anything, but im not sure if it should